# Один международный сайт или много локальных сайтов?

Tags: seo

В SEO не силён, прошу растолковать, как лучше действовать в ситуации с досками объявлений.

Что лучше делать:

Один сайт на разных языках, с дублями страниц на всех поддерживаемых языках? (Как в таком случае решить вопрос с дублями страниц?)

Или делать несколько локальных сайтов для продвижения каждого в определённом регионе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как насчет "многоязычности" сайта? В этом случае надо будет только добавить переводы страниц.

---

ЗЫ

А CMS-ка какая?

---

**UP**

Ну и зеркала поближе к целевой аудитории...)

Comment: @Zerglyn 1, CMS своя. Я имею ввиду то, что в урле есть ключевые слова и они тоже на разных языках, так же как и содержание страниц. Т.е. получается, что одна и та же страница имеет несколько копий на разных языках. С точки зрения seo, это правильно? Может, выгоднее сделать отдельный сайт для каждого языка?

Comment: Альясы URL-ов тоже можно сделать "языкозависимыми". Т.е. применяется правило: в зависимости от языка мы для этой страницы показываем _такой _ URL. Пример: с рус.переводом используется

    http://yoursite.ru/vse_vmeste/

с бел.переводом - 
    http://yoursite.by/talaka/

с анг.переводом - 
    http://yoursite.gb/all_together/

Как-то так :)

Comment: Почему не отдельный сайт для каждого языка - все просто. При добавлении материала по предложенной схеме вы добавляете только переводы для каждого языка, синхрон - автоматом (это же зеркало;-)).

На отдельных сайтах придется добавлять материалы **для каждого сайта отдельно**. Если это в меру статичный сайт - вроде не очень страшно... А если пользователи могут публиковать *свои* статьи? Кто будет отслеживать и синхронизировать? Вместо пустой страницы (без синхронизации материала *не будет вообще*) при отсутствии перевода в моем варианте просто выдается статья на языке оригинала.

Comment: А если пользователь из Австралии захочет почитать на немецком, или украинском, или русском? Посылать его на другой сайт?